# How to extract and save LSB into a byte array?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, steganography

my intension in the function below is to extract the least significant bit from every byte of the file and store it into a byte array but I've been struggling to do so.

Inside the while loop I extract the lsb with the help of `&` and then I want to add this extracted bit to the byte array. I'm not sure about the indexing and "appending" this extracted bit to the array.

```java
public byte[] extractLSB(File file, int size) {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    byte[] lsbByteArray = new byte[size];
    int arrayOffset = 0;
    int dataByte, extractedLSB;
    byte clearingByte = (byte) 0x01; // 0000 0001
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        // Read byte by byte from the file input stream
        while ((dataByte = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            // extract lsb and save it to the lsbByteArray
            /*
            //I've been trying something like this
            extractedLSB = dataByte & clearingByte; // ? get lsb
            lsbByteArray[arrayOffset] <<= 1;        // make space for a new bit
            lsbByteArray[arrayOffset] |= extractLSB; // "append" the lsb bit
            arrayOffset++;
             */
        }
        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lsbByteArray;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you are kind enough to provide.

Comment: You've provided code, which is a good start, but you haven't explained in detail what isn't working or what trouble you're having.

Comment: What do you want to do if the filestream doesn't have a multiple of 8 number of bytes? a) Discard that currently assembled byte, b) store it as is incomplete, c) shift it to the left so that it has 8 bits and it's padded with 0s in the lsbs, d) something else?

Comment: @Reti43 I'm always reading filestream which has a multiple of 8 number of bytes because the method argument `size` defines how much data was inserted before. In the `insertLSB()` method I insert one bit into each file byte at the lsb position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a byte counter in your while loop, divide by 8 to find the byte index and module 8 for the bit position.

e.g.

```
extractedLSB = dataByte & (byte) 1;
lsbByteArray[counter/8] |=  ( extractedLSB << (counter % 8));
counter++;
```

Here I use a byte in the array every 8 source bytes, thus counter / 8 to find the index, the position in the byte is the remainder of that division, so I do the shift extractedLSB << (counter % 8), finally or the result with the other bits already stored in the byte.

Comment: If I want to extract the LSB why would I use `& (byte ) 1` and not 0x01 to clear all the bits I don't care? Can you please explain me the second line?

Comment: @martink 0x01 is just the hex notation for 1. Second line contained a typo (counter & 8). Added some comment to the solution

Comment: I have a hard time imaging how the `lsbByteArray` is constructed because of the   `(counter % 8)`. The first 8 additions to the counter will result into left shift by 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0 therefore the created byte will be in a wrong order, or?

Comment: @martink actually you didn't specify the order :) I just used the more natural, lowest byte (in order) in lowest significant bit.

Comment: in the question I used "appending" this extracted bit to the array, but now I understand that I should have been more specific. So the left shifting should be by 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 ? but this will not work with '%'

Comment: @martink just replace with (7-(counter%8)) in this case, but I must say that I don't think this is the right order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231384/discussion-between-martink-and-rocco).

Comment: @martink If you embedded the bits from MSB to LSB, then shift the bits like you did in the question. `int index = counter / 8; lsbByteArray[index] = (lsbByteArray[index] << 1) | extractedLSB; counter++`.